# Help with Error: types/values length mismatch Solidity Remix

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

first of all sorry for this amateur problem, I just started learning and this error is driving me crazy since I suspect it's a really dumb thing what I'am missing. I've have already deployed my contract, but when I try to use the this function I get this error:

```
transact to IUniswapV2Router02.swapExactETHForTokens errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":4,"values":5}, value={"types":["uint256","address[]","address","uint256"],"values":["10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","",",  0xaa587eF3dea527A1B78bE9d3e410c128Cfa55ba1","0x2d855dCb1848F9624FEf4C98a6C68294025C9Fb0","1623944925"]}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.1.2)
```

This is the functions that I'm calling:

```
 function swapETHForExactTokens(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
```

As far as I know address[] must be used with the [] but looks like the brackets are not needed when I input the data calling the function. The problem seems to be in the amount of values, for some reason there's some kind of invisible value thats being detected between uint amountOut and address[].

```
["10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","",",  0xaa587eF3dea527A1B78bE9d3e410c128Cfa55ba1"
```

Comment: Try this: `"10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",["0xaa587eF3dea527A1B78bE9d3e410c128Cfa55ba1"],"0x2d855dCb1848F9624FEf4C98a6C68294025C9Fb0","1623944925"`, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You're submitting a direct addresses while you should add them in encoded JSON array ,eg you want to add 0x0000 and 0x1111 addresses:

```
0x0000,0x1111 ...etc
```

in the input add them as an encoded array ,eg :

```
["0x0000","0x1111"]
```